# How to find records that exist in all 4 tables? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, exists

I have to migrate records from one system to another. There is 4 different tables. First table contains all information about each user. Each row has unique ID that is primary key. So I need to grab primary key from table one and find matching record in other 3 tables. Those tables have foreign key that we should use to match users. Here is example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users AS ur
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA AS a
    WHERE ur.ur_id = a.a_urid
)

//Maybe second option can be to use INNER JOIN
SELECT *
FROM Users AS ur
    INNER JOIN TableA AS a
        ON ur.ur_id = a.a_urid
    INNER JOIN TableB AS b
        ON ur.ur_id = b.b_urid
    INNER JOIN TableC AS c
        ON ur.ur_id = c.c_urid
```

Query above will return matching records only for Users and Table A. I'm wondering if I can match all records from Users table that have matching user ID in table A, B and C. How that can be achieved in SQL Server 2008? Or I would need to add/import each table individually? If anyone can help with this task please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Inner join each table... seems logical

Comment: That `inner-join` tag you have looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intersect`:

```
select u.id
from users u
intersect
select a.a_urid
from a
intersect
select b.b_urid
from b
intersect
select c.c_urid
from c;
```

Another way is to use `exists`:

```
SELECT ur.*
FROM Users ur
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA AS a WHERE ur.ur_id = a.a_urid) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB AS b WHERE ur.ur_id = b.b_urid) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC AS c WHERE ur.ur_id = c.c_urid) ;
```

Using a `JOIN`, you have to be careful.  The result set might contain duplicates.  And removing the duplicates could be very expensive.